# In java SSL why is Diffie Hellman Key Exchange always using the same modulus and base?

Tags: java, ssl, diffie-hellman

I wrote a test client in java using the HttpsURLConnection class and connected to Tomcat 8.

I ran with the following settings

-Dhttps.cipherSuites=TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
-Dhttps.cipherSuites=TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

From the SSL debugging a see the DH Modulus and DH Base are always the same.  I thought the DHE would cause the modulus and base to change for each connection.
Are these values hard coded into the JVM?  Why do they stay the same even for DHE?

Answer (score 0):

Consider having a look at the [Sample program](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#DH2Ex) in the Oracle documentation for Diffie Hellman Key Exchange.

As long as the `run(String mode)` method is invoked with `"GENERATE_DH_PARAMS"`, the base and modulus parameters are generated.

Comment: I want to know what is happening when I use the HttpsURLConnection class.  What is java doing in this case?